# LogCat with Unity Android problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am being forced to test the input from a touch on my android phone. I have it all running perfectly etc. But I can't see my logs to help me debug it. Here is my code to try and debug it.

```
string side = "not touched";

if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
{
    if (Input.touchCount <= 1) 
    {
        myTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(myTouch.position);
    }

    if (touchPos.x < Camera.main.orthographicSize)
    {
        side = "Left side touched";
        //Begin Section: Touch left side
        if (touchPos.y > 0)
        {
            side += ": Top";
            yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y + (paddleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            side += ": Bottom";
            yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y - (paddleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        //End of section
    }
    Debug.Log(side);
}
```

All I am doing is seeing if I touched the left side on the top or bottom. I used debug.Log(); but I can't see what it is displaying because I have to debug on Android device. I tried the following command

`adb logcat -s Unity`

and ended it as soon as I touched the screen but my log was no where. I checked the log for a really long time to no result.

**Question: How can I see only the things I want to print using Debug.Log();**

I am aware of tags and filters but none have worked and I can't find results anywhere.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried testing with Unity Remote instead? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-remote-5-preview.398791/

Comment: Although it's good to know about Unity remote, it's rarely helpful.  It is ***only a remote mouse for the editor***, you can test nothing about builds.  It has absolutely no connection to a build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Answer. [This](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12047) brings the unity console inside of your build works on Android, ios and basically everything. Instructions on how to set it up are in the link. Much easier and better that looking at the logcat.

Alternatively you might want to implement your own developers console. Here is a [GitHub](https://github.com/gzuidhof/GConsole) repo to help you get started.

---

Note that on a Mac for example to view the logs, (1) connect the Android to a Mac with USB, then (2) in Terminal

```
you$ cd /Users/you/Library/Android/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
you$ ./adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm
```

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes the LogViewer is one of those hidden gems on the asset store. I cant even remember how I found it.